# What terminal emulators support tmux control mode?

Tags: terminal, tmux, iterm

`tmux` has its *control mode*, activated with `-CC`, to allow the terminal emulator to control tmux. iTerm2 uses this to great effect for allowing tmux windows to appear as separate iTerm windows.

Are there other terminal emulators that support control mode? I am particularly interested in terminal emulators / SSH clients for Windows that might offer such functionality, but Linux/Unix ones are interesting as well.

Comment: Have you ever succeeded in using iterm2 + ssh + tmux -CC? If so, could you possibly edit the question (or a pastebin somewhere) with details?

Comment: @bmargulies I just run `tmux -CC` in my SSH session from iterm2 and it works.

Comment: Cygwin would be a possibility?

Comment: There's a feature request for Terminator: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1301605

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335101/linux-terminal-emulator-for-tmux-control-mode

Comment: There's a feature request for ConEmu, too: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/578

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Edit**: See the other answer, **give a try to [EternalTerminal](https://github.com/MisterTea/EternalTerminal)**. It has tmux -CC support and can be installed on Linux. It may not be exactly what you need, though.

What you are asking does not seem to be developed on Linux yet with the mainstream terminal emulators:

- **Terminator** has [an open issue](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/79), somebody seems to be working on it actively.
- **Gnome-terminal** doesn't seem to have any support. There is an open bug in upstream bugzilla: [GNOME/vte#2177 - tmux integration](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/2177).
- **Konsole** has an open bug, [bug 372496 - Support tmux control mode](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372496).
- **Eterm**: [Nothing](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eterm/+bugs?field.searchtext=tmux&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=).
- **Rxvt**: [Nothing](https://sourceforge.net/p/rxvt/bugs/search/?q=tmux).
- **wezterm**: has an open bug: [Support tmux control mode #336](https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/336)
- **alacritty**: [has an open issue](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/2410).

List not exhaustive; comments are welcome.

Another idea would be to run your dear Iterm2 mac binary in your Linux environment. But the solutions currently available will not support it:

- [**Darling**](http://www.darlinghq.org/) ? It uses a Wine-like approach but *"At this point, does not yet run OS X application with a GUI"*
- [**Maloader**](https://github.com/shinh/maloader#readme) ? "Running all Mac binaries isn't my goal. Only command line tools such  as compiler tool chain can be executed by this loader" .

Comment: Tilix (formerly terminix) has an open issue as well: https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/480

Comment: Is EternalTerminal a terminal emulator? They say it's kind of like mosh but with support for tmux control mode. With iTerm2, you can open a new tab and it is connected to the same host as the original tab.

Comment: Kitty issue: https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/480

Comment: Seems like Hyper (https://hyper.is) will get proper support once this plugin is finalized: https://github.com/MisterTea/hyper-htm.

Comment: As I commented in the other answer, EternalTerminal doesn't seem to be a terminal emulator, and doesn't supply what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 6):

[EternalTerminal](https://github.com/MisterTea/EternalTerminal) has `tmux -CC` support and connection persistence.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Unless I am missing something EternalTerminal is a remote shell ala ssh, not a gui terminal emulator ala Konsole, Terminator, etc.

Answer (score -5):

On Windows try ConEmu, for Linux GNU Screen, because tmux sessions are like `screen -d -m` (other sessions on same instance `screen -x`)