# How to make scrolling in tmux smoother?

Tags: tmux, scrolling

I am using the below configuration -
`setw -g mouse on`

to use mouse scrolling within tmux sessions.

However, I notice the scrolling is not as smooth as an the Terminal.

Is there any tweaking/configuration i need to apply in tmux config to make the user experience better?

Answer (score 1):

Tmux runs in a terminal window - so scrolling can only be done line by line.

If it is that important to you and you are using a Mac you can try [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-tmux-integration.html). It has support to use tmux in control mode so I imagine scrolling would be done at the UI level (haven't tested it though).

For Linux look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280829/46158).

Comment: I'm using windows actually

Comment: @DarshanL You are on unix.stackexchange .. are you on WSL? See https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3656

Comment: Okay, actually I'm running tmux from windows, tmux server session is running on Linux

Comment: Beware: this will make iterm spawn many iterm windows (depending on number of tmux windows you have). Also, you won't be able to use tmux hotkeys any longer